# I get LookUp Error in Google Cloud Run for my Flask Python App when using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, google-cloud-run

So I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPFDg5znLTM in order to deploy my Flask app on google cloud run using dockerfile. Although, when tested normally, the app is running normally and handles the 'POST' requests I send via POSTMAN, when deployed I get the following LookUp Error.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/app/run.py", line 30, in get_text_prediction
    results=tokenize_ingredient( json['text'])
  File "/app/Ingredients.py", line 139, in tokenize_ingredient
    tokenized = word_tokenize(chunk)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 130, in word_tokenize
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 107, in sent_tokenize
    tokenizer = load("tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle".format(language))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 750, in load
    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 875, in _open
    return find(path_, path   [""]).open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 583, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError:
```

Inside my dockerfile, I have already used these lines:

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m nltk.downloader punkt
RUN python -m nltk.downloader averaged_perceptron_tagger
RUN python -m nltk.downloader wordnet
RUN pip install gunicorn
```

and inside my requirements.txt file there is:

```
Flask~=2.0.1
nltk~=3.6.2
numpy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, putting

```
-d /usr/local/nltk_data
```

inside the dockerfile fixed the issue like this:

```
# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m nltk.downloader punkt -d /usr/local/nltk_data
RUN python -m nltk.downloader averaged_perceptron_tagger -d /usr/local/nltk_data
RUN python -m nltk.downloader wordnet -d /usr/local/nltk_data
RUN pip install gunicorn
```

Comment: Why did that fix the problem?

Comment: No idea, probably google cloud run was downloading them elsewhere and could not find them when running.